# Error when installing SQL Server on new machine

Tags: installation, sql

I am installing SQL Server on a brand new laptop with no previous users. Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH9aY.png]

Has anyone seen this before and know the cause of it?

Comment: This article may be useful, while the error is not identical it is similar. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352413/cant-install-sql-server-2014-on-windows-7-hresult-0x8007370b (props to [Sirar Salih](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352413/cant-install-sql-server-2014-on-windows-7-hresult-0x8007370b "Sirnar Salih") for the inital answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I searched for your error I got a pretty lengthy answer:  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/error-1935an-error-occurred-during-the/7105ee7e-ab45-4bd2-b5db-a3e9002f7f9e

Haven't tried it, but hopefully it points you in the right direction
Here are the steps it provides:

```
If you receive a 1935 error when you try to install software, the Windows
file system transaction log has become corrupted. The transaction log is 
used by the Windows file system to recover when a file error occurs. It can 
also happen if there is an error with the installation of .netframework.

Step 1: To correct this install error, you need to clear the log.
a.    Open an Administrator command prompt: Right-click Start > All Programs > 
Accessories > Command Prompt and select "Run as Administrator" and click 
"Allow" for the elevation prompt
b.    In the command prompt, type the command below:
fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\
c.    This assumes that C: is the drive in which Vista is installed. If it 
is installed on another drive like D:, please change the drive letter 
appropriately.
d.    Reboot the system.
e.    Install the software and check.
Step 2: Check if you are able to install in clean boot.
“How to perform Clean Boot” http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135      

Note: Please ensure that the computer is set to start as usual by following 
the step 7 from the article.
Step 3: Repair .net framework and check.
Repair the Microsoft .NET Framework installation
To do this, follow these steps:
a.    Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Add or Remove 
Programs.
b.    In the Currently installed programs list, click Microsoft .NET 
Framework, and then click Change/Remove.
c.    Click Repair, and then click Next.
Diana
Microsoft Answers Support Engineer
Visit our Microsoft Answers Feedback Forum and let us know what you think.
```